# What about using your "Full width slider" with simple fading effect instead of moving L<->R?

Tags: slider, fade, jssor

I'm graphic designer, trying to use your great "Full width slider", thank you so much for it !
I want to change moving L<->R to fading effect, because I'm working with a fixed background.
Is it possible ? Or am I loosing our time ?

Thanks a lot again,
And have a nice day,

Antoine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-jquery.html
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Fade
        { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
        ];

        var options = {
            $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);


        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            if (bodyWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thx, with my graphic designer "subzero level" in dev', it seems helpfull, but I can't paste it the good way to make it work. Don't want to disturb you too much, you've already done a lot. Keep trying.